# how to avoid heavy dependency

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies, disk-usage, latex

I have a limited SSD hard drive. So I cannot install any software on my Ubuntu.

I just tried to install a very simple application: **texmaker**

```
sudo apt-get install texmaker
[sudo] password for arash: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  asymptote asymptote-doc ibus-qt4 libgsl0ldbl libibus-qt1 libpoppler-qt4-4
  preview-latex-style psutils texlive-lang-english texlive-latex-extra
  texlive-latex-extra-doc texlive-pictures texlive-pictures-doc texmaker-data
Suggested packages:
  gv xpdf gsl-ref-psdoc gsl-doc-pdf gsl-doc-info gsl-ref-html python-pygments
  dot2tex libtcltk-ruby texlive-lang-all
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  asymptote asymptote-doc ibus-qt4 libgsl0ldbl libibus-qt1 libpoppler-qt4-4
  preview-latex-style psutils texlive-lang-english texlive-latex-extra
  texlive-latex-extra-doc texlive-pictures texlive-pictures-doc texmaker
  texmaker-data
0 to upgrade, 15 to newly install, 0 to remove and 6 not to upgrade.
Need to get 454 MB of archives.
After this operation, 665 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Why such huge dependency? Are they all really necessary? Any way to have the software with lighter installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texmaker is a particular case. Whomever packaged it, correctly assumed it will be used to create and compile LaTeX documents, and thus [marked TexLive as a recommended dependency](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/texlive). TexLive is a bit of a monster, the complete package suite is over 1 Gb; Texmaker marks the most common modules, that should cover most users needs.

You can instruct `apt` to install Texmaker without the recommended packages:

`sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install texmaker`

Now you should have Texmaker installed, but are unable to compile LaTeX documents; for that you must install TexLive. Fortunately, [the `texlive` package marks few dependencies](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/texlive):

`sudo apt-get install texlive`

This gets you a minimal compiler, many common LaTeX modules and fonts will not be available.

If you need a LaTeX module that is not present in base packages, then the best alternative is to [manually install TexLive from CTAN](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installation#Custom_installation_with_TeX_Live) and use [`tlmgr`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html) to cherry pick the modules you need.

Answer (score 0):

You see it depends...
We can assume that when you install one of the first applications on your fresh Ubuntu installation where there are no dependencies, some dependencies will be required.

But as time goes by, there will be many cases when dependencies required by `apt-get` overlap and there will be no need for downloading them again.

**e.g.**

- App A needs dependencies [ "dep3", "dep6", "dep87", "dep45" ] = 1000MB
- App B needs dependencies [ "dep3", "dep6", "dep87" ] = 2MB, because some were already installed.

Comment: I completely agree. But are they all really necessary? sometimes installing a software via different packages save the space.

Comment: Yes they are required. There is no way around it, removing the required dependency will break the build of your application. You can look for alternatives of your software that weights less. And  please mark answer as useful if it helped you.